# tintColor appearing darker on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, uicolor, tintcolor

When I use the `tintColor` property of any UIKit object. the colour always appears darker on the iPhone 6 plus. Is there a reson for this?
below is a screenshot of the same test on both iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus. The UIColor assigned to the blue square and the icon (UIButton tint colour) are exactly the same? I can't find anyone with a similar problem:

[image]

[image]

here is one with UISegmentedControl:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the original images? Maybe your 3x-image has more transparency than your 2x-image?

Comment: they are using the same image resource

Comment: it is not just images, it behaves the same when I apply a tint colour to say, a UISegmentedControl

Comment: @Mats I've edited my post with a new screenshot

Comment: Did you make sure none of the accessibility options, like "Increase Contrast", are on?

Comment: @EricS omg thanks. It's been bugging me for a while. (Wasn't my iPhone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone 6+ in question had the 'darken colours' option in 'accessibility' -> 'Increase Contrast' selected.

thanks @EricS!